# dont show modules

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am doing a joomla 2.5 project

I put this `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="izquierdo" style="none"/>` and it shows me nothing.

The positions in my template is this:

```
<positions>
    <position>izquierdo</position>
    <position>extranet</position>
    <position>menuPrincipal</position>
```

The status of this module is public.

Any ideas, am I miss something?

I found something strange.
if I put my route and at the end add `?tp=1` it shows me all my postions and it shows me my module (I see the image and other thinks), but with the normal router (without ?tp=1) I don't see anything.

This is my xml template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 1.6//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/1.6/template-install.dtd">
<extension version="2.5" type="template" client="site">
    <name>arquero</name>
    <creationDate>10/10/09</creationDate>
    <author>Ron Severdia</author>
    <authorEmail>mpiedra@edosoftfactory.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://www.kontentdesign.com</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <description>ARQUERO_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <files>
        <folder>html</folder>
        <folder>css</folder>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>js</folder>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
        <filename>ajax.php</filename>
        <filename>component.php</filename>
    </files>

    <positions>
        <position>izquierdo</position>
        <position>extranet</position>
        <position>menuPrincipal</position>
        <position>carrusel</position>
        <position>noticias</position>
        <position>footer</position>
        <position>debug</position>
    </positions>
</extension>
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide us with the whole manifest file for your template?

Comment: Did you enable the module and assigned it to the desire pages?

Comment: yes Irfan I enable the module but I don´t asigne to any page, because I want to show in my index.php (in the template) so I use  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="izquierdo" />

Comment: @user852610:In that case it will not work. Firstly enable the module for all pages.And check that your module appears?Without enabling for pages you cant see it.Let me know if it does not clear.Or please describe more what you try to accomplish?

Comment: Could you explain: "I want to show in my index.php" ? Thanks.... Do you want to show it only in the homepage ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fine your template. But try style="xhtml" on your jdoc statement.

And another guess is please check again the assignment of pages for your module from the backend. Most probably you might select "No pages" for the module assignment.

Thank you.